# Issues loading Font Awesome into FontBook

Tags: macos, font-awesome, photoshop

I have successfully downloaded the free Font Awesome 5.11 SVG pack containing Solid, Regular and Brands, however, I can only view and use the Brands and Regular packs. I am using Mac OS 10.14.6. I have tried deleting and re-downloading the packs, dragging and dropping the Solid pack into my FontBook, but still the only ones that appear are the other 2. Because of that, using the icons in Photoshop or anywhere else will not properly display the Solid icons (only the square). The icons from the other 2 packs load properly in Photoshop. Ideas?